# Kotlin How do I use Realtime Database in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, mpandroidchart

I am trying to use the realtime database in a chart but it seems to not be able to convert the values in the database to a float.

The code below is how I have the graph set up.

Fragment.kt

```
private fun setBarChart() {
        databaseReference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {


                val testMon = snapshot.child("user_data/most_recent_per_day/Mon").value.toString().toFloat()

                val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
                entries.add(BarEntry(test, 0))
                entries.add(BarEntry(10f, 1))
                entries.add(BarEntry(5f, 2))
                entries.add(BarEntry(20f, 3))
                entries.add(BarEntry(15f, 4))
                entries.add(BarEntry(19f, 5))
                entries.add(BarEntry(19f, 6))

                val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Cells")

                val labels = ArrayList<String>()
                labels.add("Mon")
                labels.add("Tue")
                labels.add("Wed")
                labels.add("Thu")
                labels.add("Fri")
                labels.add("Sat")
                labels.add("Sun")
                val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
                barChart.data = data // set the data and list of lables into chart

                barChart.setDescription("Set Bar Chart Description")  // set the description

                //barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
                barDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)

                barChart.animateY(5000)
            }
```

When i set a value of the graph as `testMon = snapshot.child("user_data/most_recent_per_day/Mon").value.toString().toFloat()` it gives a numException. The BarEntry() only accepts a Float as the first parameter.

Below is the logcat.

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
        at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
        at com.fitnessproject.fragments.StatsFragment$setBarChart$1.onDataChange(StatsFragment.kt:66)
```

Any idea how to convert my database values to a Float correctly?

I don't understand why it's giving an error since it's asking for a Float and I am converting the database value to a Float. So what is the actual reason for throwing a numException??

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate this issue by running the app before creating the `Mon` value

The error still occurs when re-running the app with `Mon` already set, this seems to be happening because the value of `Mon` was cached as null.

This may also be happening because `user_data/most_recent_per_day/Mon` does not exist.

I found 2 ways to fix your issue, you can update the value of `Mon` or you can clear the app storage, both worked for me.

Also, consider adding an integrity check before attempting to convert to a float, if you add text to `Mon` it will crash your app

Comment: What do you mean by integrity check?

Also the path user_data/most_recent_per_day/Mon does exist in the database so I don't see why this should be a problem.

Comment: I mean, checking if the string can be converted to a float, if you accidentally set mon to `"2,4"` int won't work because it expects `2.4`, i explained why this may be happening even if `Mon` exists, mon may be cached as null, try to update the mon or clear the app storage

Comment: The value I have is an int, for example the path has the value 230. Trying to convert this gives an input of null when trying to convert it for some reason. I still have no clue on how to fix this

Comment: The value is null, this is clear from the error, it says that it cannot convert the string `"null"` to a float. So you are not converting 230 to a float you are trying to convert "null" to a float, have you tried clearing the app storage? If this doesn't fix the problem it must be a problem with the path.